# How do I join two linked lists in C?

Tags: linked-list, append

I'm wanting to complete two linked lists in preparation for an exam
here is what I have so far
1 - reverse the elements in a linked list
2 - append list2 to the end of list one

I got help with the reverse function off someone in my course and have tried to comment out each step to understand what is going on but I am struggling. If you could also help me out with that it would be fantasticcaalll

In the combine function I am just confused overall
When do I use '&' and when do I use '*'?

```
typedef struct node *list;

typedef struct node {
    int   value;
    list  whateverNextIsCalled;
} node;

// Reverse list
list reverse (list inputList){
    list outputList = NULL;

    while (inputList != NULL) {

       /*
        nodePtr points to the first element in the inputList
        */
        node *nodePtr = inputList;

       /* 
        Make the head pointer of inputList point to the next element
        */
        inputList = inputList->whateverNextIsCalled;

       /*
        ???? help point 1
        */
        nodePtr->whateverNextIsCalled = outputList;

       /*
        ???? help point 2
        */
        outputList = nodePtr;
    }
    return outputList;
}

// Add one list to the end of another
void combine (list list1, list list2){

   /*
    Point to the first value of list1 
    */
    node *current = list1;

   /*
    Find the last node of list1
    */
    while(current->whateverNextIsCalled != NULL) {
        current = current->whateverNextIsCalled;
    }
    //connect the last node of toList and the first node of fromList
    current->whateverNextIsCalled = &list2;

    list1 = current;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just reach to the last of the first linked list and in its next where there will be null just put the start of next linked list

i dint understand why you have reversed the list

Comment: I have a prac exam where we will be told to write a reverse/append/add function... so i'm just practising

Comment: How do I actually write that out though? I don't really understand the topic

Comment: see each list if its not a circular list then it will must have  NULL at its end node next address , so if you want to add any list then just put some thing like, suppose i am running the loop of first list , be sure that you run the loop like  while(p->next) not (while(p), in first case it will stop at last node and you can say p->next = secondList (start address of second list), now if you run loop like while(p), then it will stop on NULL, so you will not be able to store address in NULL, because it wont be a node, it will be simply a NULL

Comment: similarly if you want to reverse then do the same thing , if its double linked list , means if it contains next address as well as previous address then you can reach at the end node, and traverse back through prev address, but if its a single link list then you have to take a swapping logic ,

Comment: if you want to append then stop just a point of before you have to append, and insert new address in the node you stopped, and in then new node add address of next node where you stopped :-)